# Disable ATI Radeon HD6470 in Dell Vostro 3350 and use integrated Intel in core i5

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, radeon, ati, vga

At the moment ATI Radeon HD6470 hasn't working proprietary driver.
Open source driver works not well too: the card heats and cooler works very loud and notebook becomes hot.
I would like to use integrated Intel's video card until this problem be solved, but I don't know how to switch to it and if it will work well with external monitor through VGA port.

Answer (score 1):

my case: Thinkpad T500: ATI HD3650 -> Intel 
I think I did similar operation just minutes ago. First and foremost - **simply switching option in the BIOS to 'Integrated' resulted in Ubuntu booting into command line only, without desktop.** 
 I did the following to solve my problem (general outline):

1. Changed the BIOS display setting to 'Integrated' and booted into command line
2. Uninstalled ATI drivers (proprietary) as per http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx
3. Rebooted

For software switcher you may try the **switcheroo** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Comment: There is no setting in my BIOS to manipulate graphics.

Comment: I can't help you then. I've never fiddled with software methods for switching graphics. **switcheroo** is the only hint I have for you https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Comment: Thanks. I use it at the moment to swithc Radeon card off and stay with integrated one. But for some reason my laptop is still heating :(

Comment: Heating is a whole another story. A really nasty one unfortunatelly http://askubuntu.com/questions/72121/what-is-a-realistic-date-for-the-kernel-power-regressions-fixes You may start here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1822629&page=23

Answer (score 0):

If you have not yet resolved your problems you could try the solution outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/207270/82517) by user [Nick Andrik](https://askubuntu.com/users/45233/nick-andrik). This is the only thing that has worked for me after 6 months of searching and trying all sorts of solutions.

"For those who have hybrid systems (ATI/intel) and fglrx has stopped working in 12.10, then the problem might be like the one described here (fglrx incompatibility with the recent version of the intel driver): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-updates/+bug/1068404

What I would suggest would be

Remove all the fglrx* packages:

sudo apt-get purge fglrx*

Add my PPA in your repositories list:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrikos

Update your package information:

sudo apt-get update

Update the fglrx and intel drivers:

sudo apt-get install fglrx xserver-xorg-video-intel

Don't forget to enable the fglrx driver

sudo aticonfig --initial --force"